# How to fill dynamically expanding HTML file with templates filled with python data

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, parsing, jinja2

I have a HTML template for one message (i receive messages via `Slack-API`).
I want to fill the template with information from API and than stick templates together, in new HTML file (Output file will look like a chat-wall with every message from the chat).

Because of the chats different size, i can't make full template for the whole chat. So, i'm trying to expand my output-HTML dynamically, with my templates, filled with data.

I defined some CSS-classes in the output HTML, but they are not so important for this question, so, there is a single message html-example, which i append to the output-html:

```
<div class='message_body'>
    <div class="message_header">
        <strong class="user_name">Some UserName</strong>
        <span class="date">11.12.23 2:22</span>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <ol class="ordered_list">
        <li class="message_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur...<br />And second line</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

I thought to save this template as a python string variable, than use "f"strings to add some data in it and than just write every filled template-string in `output.html`.

But, it doesn't look optimised for me. Is there any better solutions how can i dynamically create HMTL with python-parsed data?

I've heard about `Jinja` and `airum` but i can't choose between them.

In addition, is there any other optimised solutions?

**UPD**:Added chat-html example.
[image]

Every message in this example is created with that html example. `Replies` - is just an expandable list-menu with same message-templates.

Comment: use any of the template engines like Jinja2, and write a `for` loop in the template and supply a list with chat objects. Why do you display the chat in an `ol` tag

Comment: @rioV8, this is not a chat template, this is a single message box template. I'll attach the example.

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<br>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-br-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all HTML tags.